# How to alert a special thing according to what is checked in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
if (map == "checked") { 
    alert("map ok")
}
if (joueurs == "ckecked") {     
        alert("joueurs ok")
}
if (point == "checked") {   
        alert("points ok")
}
```

Don't need to explain the actual output and I know all the if statements are totally wrong. I just wanted to show it as a clear example.

I would like the output to be like : "map player point ok" if all three a checked, "player map ok" if only player and map are checked, only "player ok" if only "player" is checked...

Ask if you want HTML (don't really thinks it is necessary)

Problem is partially resolved :

```
    if ((document.getElementById("joueurs").checked == true)) {

        alertContent = alertContent + nbjoueur + " Joueur(s), dont " + $bot.length + " bot(s) | "
    }

if ((document.getElementById("map").checked == true)) {

    alertContent = alertContent + "Map : " + map + " | "
}

 if ((document.getElementById("points").checked == true)) {
    var pointin=$.trim($("#pointsinput").val());
    if($("#pointsinput").val().length > 0) {

    alertContent = alertContent + "Partie a " + points + " point(s) |"
    }
    else {
alert("Le champ points n'est pas rempli !");
return;
    }
    alert(alertContent);
window.open('mailto:mathieu.labourier@gmail.com?subject=Formulaire Quake&body=' + alertContent);

}
```

The problem is that the mail body is empty, but alert return the correct text...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build the output before you display it.  So, in the example you have provided:

```
var alertContent = "";
if (map == "checked") { 
    alertContent = "map";
}
if (joueurs == "checked") { 
    alertContent = alertContent + (alertContent) ? " " : "" + "joueurs";
}
if (point == "checked") { 
    alertContent = alertContent + (alertContent) ? " " : "" + "points";
}
if (alertContent) alert(alertContent + " ok");
```

The only complexity is adding spaces between the words where required - which is what the `(alertContent) ? " " : ""` statements do.

Comment: Ok, it was so simple, just one question, what does (alertContent) mean when it is between parenthesis ?

Comment: alertContent is the name of the string variable. In this context, alertContent + (alertContent) ? " " : "" + "joueurs"; Wayne put it in parentheses to identify it as the predicate of the ternary operator.

Comment: A Javascript 'if' statement is deemed to be true if the result of the condition is a "truthy" value.  There are a number of different types of "truthy" values and one of them is a non-empty string.  So, in this case, I am testing that alertContent is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to use an array and join the array with spaces to generate the message:

```
var items = [];

if (map == "checked") { 
    items.push("map");
    alert("map ok")
}
if (joueurs == "ckecked") { 
    items.push("player");    
    alert("joueurs ok")
}
if (point == "checked") {
    items.push("point");
    alert("points ok")
}

if(items.length > 0){
    var message = items.join(" ") + "ok";
    alert(message);     
}
```

And another option would be a mask variable:

```
var mask = 0;

if (map == "checked") { 
    mask += 1;
    alert("map ok");
}
if (joueurs == "ckecked") { 
    mask += 2;    
    alert("joueurs ok");
}
if (point == "checked") {
    mask +=4;
    alert("points ok");
}

if(mask == 7){
    alert("map player point ok");
}
else if (mask == 3){
    alert("player map ok");
}
else if (mask == 1){
    alert("player ok");
}
```